# Making columns out of spans

Tags: css

I recive `{patients}` and place it into a div:

```
<div className="patients">
   {patients}
</div>
```

It contains *Name* and *Surname*, each row in two spans:

[image: Dev Tools]
(Dev Tools)

[image: Current state]
(Current state)

How can style those spans into columns (table-like)?

[image: Expexted result]
(Expexted result)

---EDIT---

Content of `{patients}` changes. It's a result of searching, so different names come, sometimes more, sometimes less. I can't apply a style to them separatly.
See the code.

Comment: what have you tried ? display, float even position can do this .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flexbox is perfect for this kind of layout. Create the flexbox layout in each row by giving the `.patient` wrapper `display: flex;`:

```
.patient {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

The `justify-content: space-between` rule puts the spans on the left and right ends of the available space, one of my favorite things flexbox can do.

```css
.patients {
  border: 1px solid black;
  max-width: 250px;
}
.patient {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
}
.patient span {
  padding: 0 20px; // gives a little space around each span
}
.patient:first-child {
  border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="patients">
   <div class="patient">
    <span>Eri</span>
    <span>Car</span>
   </div>
   <div class="patient">
    <span>Dude</span>
    <span>Ok</span>
   </div>
   <div class="patient">
    <span>Nice</span>
    <span>One</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    <div class="patients">
      <div class="patient">
        <span>Eric</span>
        <span>Car</span>
         <span>Car</span>
      </div>
      <div class="patient">
        <span>Eric</span>
        <span>Car</span>
         <span>Car</span>
      </div>
      <div class="patient">
        <span>Eric</span>
        <span>Car</span>
         <span>Car</span>
      </div>
      <div class="patient">
        <span>Eric</span>
        <span>Car</span>
         <span>Car</span>
      </div>
    </div>

CSS
----

.patients {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: none;
}

.patient {
  display: table-row;
}

.patient > span {
  display: table-cell;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: please let me know whether the above code snippet works fine for you?

Comment: Thank you, unfortunatly I recive `{patients}` which has a dynamic content, it could be different names, sometimes more, sometimes less.

Comment: you can write patients.map(patient => return ())

Comment: In return statement yoou can return the above mark up

Comment: Where sould I write `patients.map(patient => return ())`? Maybe if you could update the answer, I'd see it all there.

Comment: Are you using any libray like react js or you are trying to do it in plane javscript?

Comment: React, this was what I have before:     
`render () {
        let patients = this.props.patients.map((p) => {
           return <PatientListItem key={p.globalId} patient={p} selected={p.globalId === this.props.selected} onClick={(e) => this.props.selectPatient(p)}/>
        });

        return ( `

Comment: So I have `(p)` instead of `patient` that you're proposing. I'll try that.

Comment: <div className="patients">
    this.props.patients.map(patient => {
         return (
                     <div className="patient" key={patient.globalId}>
                        <span>{patient.name}</span>
                        <span>{patient.surName}</span>
                     </div>
    })
</div>

Comment: In the end, instead of creating `patient` in React's code, I selected it with `.patients > * {` . Thank you for your commitment!

Comment: Sorry, missed that :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use display with table/table-row/table-cell or use display block with a fix with or make each row a flexbox with a fixed width or some other solution. There are many ways to achieve that.

Comment: Interesting, but I need a one, complete solution :) Added `display: table-row;` attribute to the `patients` class, and that alone doesn't change anything.